# How to implement weighted blended order independent transparency in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, c++, 3d, transparency

I want to implement weighted blended OIT in my C++ OpenGL 3D game, but I didn't find any C++ examples about weighted blended order independent transparency.

[Paper](http://jcgt.org/published/0002/02/09/)

- How to clear accumTexture(framebuffer attachment) to vec4(0)?
- How to clear revealageTexture(framebuffer attachment) to float(1)?

Comment: The paper you link appears to include code examples demonstrating their proposed methods. Can you describe in more detail where you've run into trouble incorporating this into your game or mod?

Comment: @DMGregory How to clear accumTexture to vec4(0) and revealageTexture to float(1)?

Comment: [glClearColor](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearColor.xhtml) and [glClear](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClear.xml)? If you're having trouble setting up and clearing render targets, then you might want to start with a few more basic OpenGL tutorials to learn the ropes before diving into graphics research whitepapers.

Comment: @DMGregory But if I bind framebuffer, I need to clear two textures by different values. How to do that?